# When using wildcards to graph metrics is there a way to force an order on the matching metrics?

Tags: graphite

I've got two graphs that use the something like the following metrics :

graph1 : oldMethod.latencies_msec.percentiles.p{25,50,75,90,95,99}

graph2 : newMethod.latencies_msec.percentiles.p{25,50,75,90,95,99}

I'd like these two graphs to use the same colors for similar metrics. I don't care much about the colours but would like the two p25s in both graphs to have the same color, the two p50s to have the same color and so on.

If I don't use wildcards and use 6 different data lines for each graph and order the metrics the same way for both graphs, then I get consistent colors but if I use wildcards the ordering of the metrics seems arbitrary.

Is there anyway to fix the ordering? If not any insight into the logic behind the metric ordering would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There is a change in works that will solve this problem. Here is the link to it in github - https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/pull/831.
You might have to do sortByName(aliasByNode(your_metrics_here, position)) to get shorter names that can be sorted conveniently for metrics to be rendered in the right order. You have to also make sure you have the same number of nodes in all the graphs to get the desired result.

Answer (score -1):

You can assign a color manually to a metric like so:

&target=color(my.data.here,"blue")

see bgcolor

http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/1.0/url-api.html#bgcolor

Now to order, you can use something like:

target=limit(sortByMaxima(my.data.here,8)